# Adding new column to Excel Source in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I am working on a SSIS project. My Source is Excel file. I am working with data from it, querying database, and retrieving some needed records.
So, question is: how to add programmatically a new data column in Excel source file and insert in these new records?

I have another question - how to delete rows from excel in sql task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would
 1. Create a new Excel file with the new column(s) using "Execute SQL Task".
e.g.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Walks` (
    ` Date` NVARCHAR(255),
     `Id` NVARCHAR(255),
    `Distance` DECIMAL,
    `Max` DECIMAL,
    `Flat Time` NVARCHAR(255)
     )
```

2. Process the existing Excel / Database and populate the new Excel.
3. Move/Copy (initially) the original Excel elsewhere
   Perhaps delete this once everything is working!
4. Rename the new Excel file as the original.

   Note:
    a) You will need to delay validation for the package 
     b) Set up a data connection for the new Excel file.
     c) Provide a variable to hold the path to the new Exel file.
     d) You will also need a File System Task to precede the "Execute SQL task" to Delete the Excel file (using the variable Excel path) so that the "Execute SQL task" can create it!

Comment: Thanks, you answer is perfect.

Comment: I have another question - how to delete rows from excel in sql task?

Comment: I don't think you can. The only option I see is to create a new Excel sheet using SQL task without the column you want to delete and copy the relevant columns across to the new sheet